# Strange 'print' behavior in IPython in PyCharm

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm, ipython

The `print` function seems to reduce the number of dots when displayed:

```py
Python 3.8.10 (default, Mar 15 2022, 12:22:08) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.22.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
PyDev console: using IPython 7.22.0
Python 3.8.10 (default, Mar 15 2022, 12:22:08) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux

In [2]: s = "A\n..... a\n..... b\n"

In [3]: print(s)
A
.. a
.. b


In [4]:
```

Nothing like this happens in the terminal:

```py
Python 3.8.10 (default, Mar 15 2022, 12:22:08) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> s = "A\n..... a\n..... b\n"
>>> print(s)
A
..... a
..... b
>>>
```

even if I run IPython in it:

```py
$ ipython

Python 3.8.10 (default, Mar 15 2022, 12:22:08) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.22.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: s = "A\n..... a\n..... b\n"

In [2]: print(s)
A
..... a
..... b


In [3]:
```

Does anyone know the reason for this behavior?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72456234/why-does-print-i-e-three-dots-in-a-row-print-blank

Answer (score 3):

I think it's related to iPython syntax for implicit line join. PyCharm may convert the three dots into an ellipsis, and interpret it as a "new line command" (like when in ipython console you break line without closing parenthesis and it expect other arguments)

Comment: [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/pycharm/comments/k6q5du/pycharm_console_not_printing_three_dots/) give the same answer, but that's all guessing...