# Why does print("..."), i.e. three dots in a row, print blank?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I'd like to print three dots in a row (to form an ellipsis), but print() prints blank.

```
print("one moment...")
one moment...
print("...")

print("..")
..
print("...abc...")
abc...
print("\u2026")
…
```

What's happening here? Why is "..." parsed in an exceptional way?

I am using ipython in PyCharm.

Comment: Ah, [here's the other question I was thinking about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72198827/strange-print-behavior-in-ipython-in-pycharm/72199210#72199210)!

Comment: Another thing that pops up sometimes - not this time it seems but still potentially worth mentioning - is charset weirdness + "smart" ellipses (U+2026). This is doubly fun when combined with anything that strips out high characters. A bare `…` turns into `â€¦` in CP-1252 - or nothing at all in 7-bit ASCII. `"…".encode('utf8').decode('ascii', errors='ignore') == ""`

Comment: This is neither an answer nor a solution, but if you really want the ellipsis, you can generate a real one from the keyboard. On Mac it’s `opt-;`, while on Windows it’s `alt-0133` where the numbers are on the numeric keypad.

Comment: I am using PyCharm on my Mac, and tried both `print('… watch this space …')` and `print('... watch this space ...')`. Both printed perfectly. Using 2021.3.1 (Community Edition).

Comment: @Manngo yes that works, but have you tried with ipython in pycharm?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Looks like this is a known issue with Pycharm where its interactive console removes the leading three periods from a print statement. [Here’s the ticket tracking this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-30598).

---

A possible workaround for now is defining something like:

```py
def iprint(obj):
    if (s:=str(obj)).startswith("..."):
        print(" "+s)
    else:
        print(s)
```

which looks like:

```py
>>> iprint("...ymmv")
 ...ymmv
```

Comment: @P2000 first reported in 2018! Seems like something they would’ve fixed by now maybe a temporary solution would be to write a custom print function that just checks `str(x).startswith(“…”)` and prepends a newline or something if true

Comment: "Seems like something they would’ve fixed by now" - you'd think so, wouldn't you? I would. But I keep encountering very old unfixed bugs in Pycharm, for example: it still doesn't recognise that the result of `functools.partialmethod()` is callable, and [it's been six years](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-18448/Code-inspector-does-not-recognize-Python-3-functoolspartialmethod-objects-as-callable)

Comment: @AaronF I don't understand either. It's a super IDE, and I'd be very happy if they just spent <20% on new features but >80% on fixes for the next 12mo.

Comment: Maybe they overrode it with some ellipsis interpretation.