# Why does splitlines() not give the expected result for triple dots in Jupyter?

Tags: python, string, jupyter-notebook

I believe the following code

```py
s = '''
...
.o.
...
'''
print(s.splitlines())
```

should print

```
['', '...', '.o.', '...']
```

Indeed, this is the case when Python is executed normally (example run on Wandbox is [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/A8Dm7CQLT93lulIe)).

But the reality is ruthless (as usual); Google Colaboratory prints a result without "triple dots":

[image]

I also tried the same code with a locally installed Jupyter (Python 3.7.13, Jupyter notebook 6.4.12, IPython 7.34.0) and it gave me the same result as Google Colaboratory.

Does anyone know what causes this deletion of the triple dots?

Comment: You can use `s.split("\n")`

Comment: @Siscall That's true. But then what makes difference between `s.splitlines()` and `s.split("\n")`...??

Comment: @siscall Google Collab returns `['', '', '.o.', '', '']` when applying `.split("\n")`

Comment: You may want to verify that `s` actually is what you expected (i,e, `'\n...\n.o.\n...\n'`) by printing it out (by removing `.splitlines()`).

Comment: @metatoaster `'\n\n.o.\n\n'`

Comment: collab is ignoring the ...

Comment: Thanks all. `print(repr(s))` gives `'\n\n.o.\n\n'`. Jupyter does something for this input... Is this a bug or a kind of Jupyter magic command that I am not aware of...?

Comment: By the way, for those who are curious about the background of why I hit this issue: I was writing a parser for the [plaintext format](https://conwaylife.com/wiki/Plaintext) for Conway's Game of Life and the above example was a simple one to check if it works. The Game of Life always surprises me...

Comment: Not a duplicate, but note, this sort of problem of mixing `...` with code seems to be a common one; [PyCharm seems to have a bug that removes leading `...` from output.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72456234/364696).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Google collab interprets `...` as part of the prompt. <s>You can change the prompt to some other string and the result will be as you expected</s> :

```
import sys
sys.ps2 = '<<<' # default value is ...

s = '''
...
.o.
...
'''
print(s.splitlines())
['', '...', '.o.', '...']
```

**EDIT:** As @user2357112 pointed out in the comments and in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72674721/9608759) changing the prompt does not affect this. Here it seemed to work because adding more lines to the beginning of the cell make Ipython interpreter think they are no longer part of the prompt. You can change your string to `'\n...\n.o.\n...'` as a workaround.

Comment: I was not aware of `sys.ps2`, which is good to know.

Comment: Editing `sys.ps2` doesn't actually affect this at all. It seems to help, but the actual reason the output looks right is that you've added more lines to the top of the notebook cell, which causes IPython to no longer think the `...`s are prompts.

Answer (score 8):

This is an [IPython feature](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/reference.html#pasting-of-code-starting-with-python-or-ipython-prompts). If IPython thinks your input looks like it was copy-pasted from another interactive session, it will strip out everything it thinks is an interactive prompt before executing the input.

This is supposed to make it easy to copy and paste code from other interactive Python sessions without having to manually take the prompts off, but it causes problems when you have *actual code* that looks like it's got interactive prompts in it.

---

Contrary to what one of the other answers claims, editing `sys.ps2` doesn't affect this at all. The prompt regexes are hardcoded. For current IPython, you can see the logic in [`IPython.core.inputtransformer2.PromptStripper`](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/8.4.0/IPython/core/inputtransformer2.py#L52), but Google Colab is currently on an old IPython version, 5.5.0, where you should look at [`IPython.core.inputtransformer.classic_prompt`](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/5.5.0/IPython/core/inputtransformer.py#L454):

```
@CoroutineInputTransformer.wrap
def classic_prompt():
    """Strip the >>>/... prompts of the Python interactive shell."""
    # FIXME: non-capturing version (?:...) usable?
    prompt_re = re.compile(r'^(>>>|\.\.\.)( |$)')
    initial_re = re.compile(r'^>>>( |$)')
    # Any %magic/!system is IPython syntax, so we needn't look for >>> prompts
    turnoff_re = re.compile(r'^[%!]')
    return _strip_prompts(prompt_re, initial_re, turnoff_re)
```

Editing `sys.ps2` only looked like it helped because `_strip_prompts` stops looking for prompts if it doesn't find any in the first two lines, and the extra code to edit `sys.ps2` meant `_strip_prompts` didn't find any prompts in those lines.

---

Unfortunately, if you want to disable this, it's going to be much more awkward than editing `sys.ps2`. I don't think there's a convenient config option. I think you'll have to retrieve the list of input cleanup transformers and remove the prompt strippers manually. On the IPython version Google Colab currently uses, that looks like this:

```
physical_line_transforms = get_ipython().input_transformer_manager.physical_line_transforms
physical_line_transforms[:] = [transformer for transformer in physical_line_transforms
                               if transformer.coro.__name__ != '_strip_prompts']
```

`coro` and `_strip_prompts` are undocumented implementation details, but I don't think there's a better way.

On a more modern IPython, the code looks like this:

```
from IPython.core.inputtransformer2 import PromptStripper
cleanup_transformers = get_ipython().input_transformers_cleanup
cleanup_transformers[:] = [transformer for transformer in cleanup_transformers
                           if not isinstance(transformer, PromptStripper)]
```

Unlike the other snippet, I think everything here is part of the documented IPython API.

Answer (score 7):

I believe that `...` at the beginning of the line indicates the secondary prompt in the [interactive mode](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#interactive-mode) (which is the mode in Jupyter and Colaboratory). You might want to try `>>>`, it is also a prompt in the interactive mode.

I think that it's better to use the string `'\n...\n.o.\n...'` instead.

Comment: Is there a difference between `'\n...\n.o.\n...' ` and the string in the question?

Comment: @Acccumulation There is no difference.